# Avoid memory leak with inner classes android

Tags: android

I am stumped on this. I can't seem to figure out how properly create new listeners in android to avoid memory leaks. Would I use a static inner class with a SoftReference to the outer class (since I need to access the outer class variables)? Or should i do something like this:

```
setScrollListener(new ScrollListner {

//methods here.

});
```

Comment: why is memory leak with inner class?

Comment: which inner class? the static one or the example i provided?

Comment: if properly used, than will not be memory leak in any case

Comment: can you elaborate more? what do you mean by properly used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A memory leak should only occur if the Scrolllistener is referenced from something outside your activity.

If you use the scrolllistener as it is in you code the listener will keep a reference to you Activity because it is an anonymous class. But the only reference to your listener will be from the views that are references from this activity. Once the activity is finished the garbage collector can clean up the whole memory at once.

Comment: I see what youre saying now. I just keep getting OOM errors when I am loading a list of about 300 items. I am unsure what is wrong. I am using the viewholder pattern, and i have no images. I figured it was my non static inner classes. I am very stuck on this.

Comment: Maybe it is the list of items itself, post more code in another question maybe we can help you